# It shows error message Cannot create OCI environment in my Visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ocilib

I am using Microsoft Visualstudio2015, i am trying to run c++ program using OCI functions, but my program terminating.

I set ocilib  path in my visual studio and it starting successfully, but i got message initialising failed in my log file

```
#include "ocilib.h"      

ofstream LogFile;        
LogFile.open("logfile.txt");
void err_handler(OCI_Error *err)
{
if(OCI_ErrorGetType(err) == OCI_ERR_ORACLE)
{
const mtext* sql =OCI_GetSql(OCI_ErrorGetStatement(err));
if(sql != NULL)
{
  LogFile<<"ERROR - SQL : "<<sql<<"\n";
}
}

LogFile<<"ERROR - MSG : "<<OCI_ErrorGetString(err)<<endl;
++nbr_error;
}


if(!OCI_Initialize(err_handler, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT))
{
 LogFile<<"ERROR - Initialise failed\n";
 exit(1);
}
```

After running the program It shows **ERROR - MSG: Cannot create OCI environment**  Program terminating,

what i supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download instantclient-basic and instantclient-sdk-windows from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/cn/topics/winsoft-085727.html.

You should choose the x86 or the x64 version based on your program.
And then decompress and merge them to one folder.

In your program,
OCI_Initialize(err_handler, **the_folder**, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT)

Answer (score 0):

Re-check your OCILIB path in Environment variables,
for example:-

```
 Copy ocilib\include\ocilib.h : to a folder listed in the compiler headers folders
 Copy ocilib\lib32 |64\ocilib [x].Lib : to a folder listed in the linker libraries folders
 Copy ocilib\lib32|64\ocilib [x]. Dll : to a folder included in the PATH environment variable
```